# Unwanted page border when I embed a document

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm able to display a pdf in a new tab of Chrome. 
But i see an unwanted frame around the page.

I use object tag to embed the document, but I also using iframe the border is always showed (with frameborder set to 0), also playing with style I don't had a better result.
i think the problems is when I create a new document this create me an html overstructure, which I don't have a need.

This is my javascript code:

```
var windowTab= window.open();
var blob = new window.Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
var file = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
windowTab.document.write('<object data="' + file + '" style="border:0px; margin:0px; padding:0px; 
width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></object>')
```

this is the resulting html:

````
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- This is my document !-->
 <object data="blob:http://localhost:8080/f3a8347d-1052-4460-acc8-ecb8d6be0861" allowfullscreen="">
   <!-- this html is unnecessary --> 
   <html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
   <embed width="100%" height="100%" src="about:blank" type="application/pdf" 
   internalid="CAE747DCA94CCEFA3C50345F9D12986A">```</body>
</html>
</object>
</body>
</html>
````

Answer (score 0):

Try setting all `border` to `0px` or `none`

```
body,
html,
object,
embed{
    border: 0px !important;
}
```

[Reference Link](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/get-rid-of-border-and-scrollbar-from-object/1572)

Answer (score 0):

Solved adding this line in my javascript:

```
newTab.document.write('<html><head><title>Document</title><style> body {margin:0px;} </style></head><body>');
```

here i add explicit margin set to 0, and now it works fine!